# Синтаксическая ошибка в IE11 при использовании webpack optimization splitChunks

Tags: javascript, webpack

Вот мой кусок кода webpack.config.js

```
entry: {
    'entry': ["@babel/polyfill", './Scripts/src/entry.js'],
    'main': ["@babel/polyfill", './Scripts/src/main.js'],
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].min.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts/assets'),
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
     ]
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
            cache: true,
            parallel: true,
            sourceMap: false,
        }),
        new OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin({})
    ],
    moduleIds: 'hashed',
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            vendor: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name: 'modules',
                chunks: 'all'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В IE11 получаю Синтаксическая ошибка в моем файле modules.js. В этом файле используется синтаксис ES6, как его перевести в ES5.

Answer (score 0):

Устанваливаете в свой проект зависимость `@babel/preset-env`.

И дальше в конфиге вебпака делаете

```js
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
    },
]
```